# How to test catch block in Java with Spock that has a simple log statement

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I have a simple Java method that I want to unit test with Spock

```
private void executeDataLoad(String sql) {
        Statement snowflakeStatement=null;
        try {

            snowflakeStatement = getSnowflakeStatement();
            log.info("Importing data into Snowflake");
            int rowsUpdated = snowflakeStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
            log.info("Rows updated/inserted:  " + rowsUpdated);
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            log.error("Error importing data into Snowflake", sqlEx);
            throw new RuntimeException(sqlEx);
        }finally{
            try {
                if (snowflakeStatement != null)
                    snowflakeStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                log.error("Error closing the statement", sqlEx);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to test the catch block in finally. It is a simple catch block which just logs a statement. All the examples I have seen only test the catch blocks that have a throw keyword inside the catch block.

How do I test to make sure that the catch block is executed ?

Comment: Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and try to always use one in your question. An isolated method without a class around it and with missing members and methods is not an MCVE as I cannot compile and run it. Also you don't show any test code, so I cannot see what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: **You don't test private methods directly.**

Instead, good testing practice is to test public methods with the necessary parameters and injected objects (often mock objects) in order to cover all execution paths in both your public and private methods. If you cannot cover private method code by calling public methods, it is a sign that

- either your class is not testable well and you should refactor
- or (part of) your private method code is unreachable and should thus be removed
- or maybe a combination of both.

Your code also suffers from the problem of instantiating its own dependencies, in this case the `Statement` object. If you could inject it as a method parameter instead of the method constructing it as a local variable, you could easily inject a mock, stub or spy and make that mock object behave as you wish in order to test different cases and execution paths in your method.

As a side note, I assume your logger is a `private static final` object. If you would make it non-final, you could replace it by a mock logger and even check if certain log methods are being called during the test. But maybe that is not so important for you, you should not over-specify and test too much. In my example I will just make it non-final in order to show you what is possible as you seem to be a beginner in test automation.

Back to testing private methods: As most mock frameworks (also Spock's) are based on subclassing or implementing the original classes or interfaces via dynamic proxies and private methods are not visible to their subclasses, you also cannot overwrite/stub the behaviour of a private method. This is yet another (technical) reason why trying to test private methods on mock objects is a bad idea.

Let us assume our class under test looks like this (please note that I made both methods package-protected so as to be able to mock/stub them):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58072937;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.sql.*;

public class SQLExecutor {
  private static /*final*/ Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQLExecutor.class);

  /*private*/ void executeDataLoad(String sql) {
    Statement snowflakeStatement = null;
    try {
      snowflakeStatement = getSnowflakeStatement();
      log.info("Importing data into Snowflake");
      int rowsUpdated = snowflakeStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
      log.info("Rows updated/inserted:  " + rowsUpdated);
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
      log.error("Error importing data into Snowflake", sqlEx);
      throw new RuntimeException(sqlEx);
    } finally {
      try {
        if (snowflakeStatement != null)
          snowflakeStatement.close();
      } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        log.error("Error closing the statement", sqlEx);
      }
    }
  }

  /*private*/ Statement getSnowflakeStatement() {
     return new Statement() {
       @Override public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException { return null; }
       @Override public int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public void close() throws SQLException {}
       @Override public int getMaxFieldSize() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public void setMaxFieldSize(int max) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public int getMaxRows() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public void setMaxRows(int max) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public void setEscapeProcessing(boolean enable) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public int getQueryTimeout() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public void setQueryTimeout(int seconds) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public void cancel() throws SQLException {}
       @Override public SQLWarning getWarnings() throws SQLException { return null; }
       @Override public void clearWarnings() throws SQLException {}
       @Override public void setCursorName(String name) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public ResultSet getResultSet() throws SQLException { return null; }
       @Override public int getUpdateCount() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public boolean getMoreResults() throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public void setFetchDirection(int direction) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public int getFetchDirection() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public void setFetchSize(int rows) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public int getFetchSize() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public int getResultSetConcurrency() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public int getResultSetType() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public void addBatch(String sql) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public void clearBatch() throws SQLException {}
       @Override public int[] executeBatch() throws SQLException { return new int[0]; }
       @Override public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException { return null; }
       @Override public boolean getMoreResults(int current) throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public ResultSet getGeneratedKeys() throws SQLException { return null; }
       @Override public int executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys) throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public int executeUpdate(String sql, int[] columnIndexes) throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public int executeUpdate(String sql, String[] columnNames) throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public boolean execute(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys) throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public boolean execute(String sql, int[] columnIndexes) throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public boolean execute(String sql, String[] columnNames) throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public int getResultSetHoldability() throws SQLException { return 0; }
       @Override public boolean isClosed() throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public void setPoolable(boolean poolable) throws SQLException {}
       @Override public boolean isPoolable() throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public void closeOnCompletion() throws SQLException {}
       @Override public boolean isCloseOnCompletion() throws SQLException { return false; }
       @Override public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException { return null; }
       @Override public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface) throws SQLException { return false; }
     };
  }
}
```

Then you could write a Spock test like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58072937

import org.slf4j.Logger
import spock.lang.Specification

import java.sql.SQLException

class SQLExecutorTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def logger = Mock(Logger)
    def originalLogger = SQLExecutor.log
    SQLExecutor.log = logger
    SQLExecutor sqlExecutor = Spy() {
      getSnowflakeStatement() >> {
        throw new SQLException("uh-oh")
      }
    }

    when:
    sqlExecutor.executeDataLoad("dummy")

    then:
    def exception = thrown RuntimeException
    exception.cause instanceof SQLException
    exception.cause.message == "uh-oh"
    0 * logger.info(*_)
    1 * logger.error(*_)

    cleanup:
    SQLExecutor.log = originalLogger
  }
}
```

As I said above, the whole interaction testing on the logger is optional and not necessary in order to answer your question. I just did it in order to illustrate what is possible.

I also do not like my own solution because you need to

- use a spy object for your class under test and
- to know about the internal implementation of `executeDataLoad(String)`, namely that it calls `getSnowflakeStatement()` in order to be able to stub out the latter method and make it throw the exception you want to be thrown in order to cover the exception handler's execution path.

Please also note that the statement `exception.cause.message == "uh-oh"` is not really necessary as it is just testing the mock. I just put it there in order to show you how the mocking thing works.

---

Now let us assume we refactor your class to make the `Statement` injectable:

```java
  /*private*/ void executeDataLoad(String sql, Statement snowflakeStatement) {
    try {
      if (snowflakeStatement == null)
        snowflakeStatement = getSnowflakeStatement();
      log.info("Importing data into Snowflake");
      // (...)
```

Then you could make `getSnowflakeStatement()` private (provided you can cover that one via another public method) and modify your test like this (removing the logger interaction testing in order to concentrate on what I am changing):

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58072937

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Statement

class SQLExecutorTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def sqlExecutor = new SQLExecutor()
    def statement = Mock(Statement) {
      executeUpdate(_) >> {
        throw new SQLException("uh-oh")
      }
    }

    when:
    sqlExecutor.executeDataLoad("dummy", statement)

    then:
    def exception = thrown RuntimeException
    exception.cause instanceof SQLException
  }
}
```

See the difference? You don't need to use a `Spy` on your class under test anymore and can just use a `Mock` or a `Stub` for the `Statement` you inject in order to modify its behaviour.

I could say and explain more, but this answer cannot replace a testing tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Remove null check in try block inside finally. Because of this null check, you can not get any exception. Just try to closing the statement without checking it.

```
private void executeDataLoad(String sql) {
    Statement snowflakeStatement=null;
    try {

        snowflakeStatement = getSnowflakeStatement();
        log.info("Importing data into Snowflake");
        int rowsUpdated = snowflakeStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
        log.info("Rows updated/inserted:  " + rowsUpdated);
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        log.error("Error importing data into Snowflake", sqlEx);
        throw new RuntimeException(sqlEx);
    }finally{
        try {
            snowflakeStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            log.error("Error closing the statement", sqlEx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still possible to get `SQLException` from `close()`. Even more, now it is possible to get `NullPointerException` in case when `getSnowflakeStatement()` failed with `SQLException`, as result the `snowflakeStatement` is null.